# i want to find address by zipcode and selected country using google api

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

i am fetching address with zipcode using google api and its work perfetcly

but i want to restrict it with select country only,how can i ?

here is my code that fetch address using zipcode how can i pass country also in this api

```
var obj = {};
        obj.address = value;


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
            //  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: obj,
            async: false,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                getValueFromZipcode = res;
                assignData(getValueFromZipcode);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                callLoader(false);
                swal({
                    title: "Something Wents Wrong", text: "", type: "error",
                    showCancelButton: false, closeOnConfirm: true, confirmButtonText: "OK",
                }, function (isConfirm) {
                    window.location = "signin";
                });
                // console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can use component filtering like :http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&components=country:US|postal_code:560068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var country = 'IN';
var postal_code = 560068;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&components=country:"+country+"|postal_code:"+postal_code+"",
        //  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: obj,
        async: false,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            callLoader(false);
            swal({
                title: "Something Wents Wrong", text: "", type: "error",
                showCancelButton: false, closeOnConfirm: true, confirmButtonText: "OK",
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                window.location = "signin";
            });
            // console.log(err);
        }
    });
```